# mocking service doesn't work when call the end-point using spring boot and cucumber

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cucumber

I am trying to mock one service when I call the end-point in the test, I am using spring boot with cucumber and I would like to mock my service but I always get the real object in return but the mock working normally when I call the service from the test directly, I created a sample to check if u can help
this is my test class

```
package com.example.demo

import com.example.demo.service.DemoService
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then
import io.cucumber.java.en.When
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberTestContext.SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE
import io.restassured.RestAssured
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.response.MockMvcResponse
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.specification.MockMvcRequestSpecification
import org.mockito.BDDMockito.given
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureWebMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get



@ContextConfiguration(classes = [DemoApplication::class])
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
class Steps {

    @LocalServerPort
    var port: Int = 0

    var demoService: DemoService = mock(DemoService::class.java)

    @Autowired
    private val webApplicationContext: WebApplicationContext? = null


    @When("call the end point")
    fun callTheEndPoint() {
        val msg: Message = Message(id = "2", text = "test")
        Mockito.`when`(demoService.getMessage()).thenReturn(msg)
        RestAssured.port = port
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost"
       var res = RestAssured.`when`().get("/").then().extract().body().`as`(Message::class.java)
        println("When is called: " + res.text)
    }

    @Then("retrieve these data")
    fun retrieveData() {
        println("Then is called")
    }
}
```

this is my RestApi

```
package com.example.demo

import com.example.demo.service.DemoService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

data class Message(val id: String?, val text: String)

@RestController
class MessageResource {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var demoService: DemoService

    @GetMapping
    fun index(): Message = demoService.getMessage()

}
```

this is my service

```
package com.example.demo.service

import com.example.demo.Message
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class DemoService {
    fun getMessage(): Message  = Message(id = "1", text = "qwerty")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var demoService: DemoService = mock(DemoService::class.java)
```

This wouldn't work in a JUnit test either. You're creating a mock of `DemoService` inside `Steps`. There is no way your spring application could pick up on the instance you've created and use it as a bean.

With JUnit you'd use:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ExampleTest {
   @MockBean
   DemoService demoService;
}
```

And with Cucumber:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
   @MockBean
   DemoService demoService;
}
```

The `@CucumberContextConfiguration` annotation is important. It tells Cucumber that it should use the `CucumberSpringConfiguration` class to create the test application context from.